# DNS Changes: Pointing one subdirectory to another host

Tags: dns, hosting

**Short Question**: 
Is it possible that example.com points to an IP address, but example.com/something points to another IP?

**More Details**:
example.com was previously hosted with my client's host company. I have designed a new website for them and now host it myself (by pointing their IP to mine). They are now letting me know that there used to be a sub-directory where another application was hosted under. It would take me a while to re-install that application in the new host, I was just wondering if it'd be possible to serve any request to that sub-directory through the old host/IP.

Comment: Please just create it as subdomain, for example blog.yourdomain.com and then point the A record via DNS setting

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. Resolving the host (example.com) is a separate task (DNS query) from connecting to the http server (HTTP connection) that the host points to. None of the URL, except for the hostname, is queried via DNS so there is no way that DNS can be made to behave differently based on other parts of the URL as it doesn't see it.

A subdomain is part of the hostname and that's why www.example.com and www1.example.com can point to different addresses. If you need to have www.example.com/something go elsewhere, you'll need to use HTTP redirects.